# Scrolling after Swiping not Working in React Native for iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler, panresponder

I am attempting to set up a scrollable list in my React Native iOS app that also enables left and right swiping. For this list, I am using ScrollView with the `PanResponder` utility in React Native for gesture handling. Currently, I am able to swipe list items left and right. However, after swiping at least one list item either left or right, I cannot seem to immediately scroll through the list. It appears that the list items remain sensitive to the scroll up/down gesture. After a few up/down gestures, the scroll finally responds. To fix this, I tried adding `handleScrollBegin` and `handleScrollEnd` functions to change the state of `swipeEnabled` depending on the state of `onScrollBeginDrag` and `onScrollEndDrag` in the ScrollView. However, this also didn't resolve the issue. Any idea how I can fix my SwipeList so as to enable scrolling after swiping? See my code below:

```
const SwipeList = ({ data }) => {

  const [swipeEnabled, setSwipeEnabled] = useState(true);
    
  const SwipeRow = ({ item, swipeEnabled }) => {
    const swipeX = new Animated.Value(0);
  
    const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => swipeEnabled,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => swipeEnabled,
      onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
        swipeX.setValue(gestureState.dx);
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: async (event, gestureState) => {
        // Handle swiping right or left here
        if (gestureState.dx > 75) {
          // Swiped right
          Animated.timing(swipeX, {
            toValue: 200,
            duration: 200,
            useNativeDriver: false,
          }).start(() => {
            console.log('Swiped right'); // Handle swiping right
          });
        } 
        else if (gestureState.dx < -75) {
          // Swiped left
          Animated.timing(swipeX, {
            toValue: 200, 
            duration: 200,
            useNativeDriver: false,
          }).start(() => {
            console.log('Swiped left'); // Handle swiping left
          });
        } 
        else {
          // Reset position
          Animated.timing(swipeX, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 200,
            useNativeDriver: false,
          }).start();
        }

        return false; // Release the touch event to the scroll
      },
    });
  
    const animatedStyle = {
      transform: [{ translateX: swipeX }],
    };
  
    return (
      <Animated.View style={[styles.listItem, animatedStyle]}>
        <RectButton style={{ flex: 1 }} {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
          <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingVertical: 20 }}>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
          </View>
        </RectButton>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  };
  
  const handleScrollBegin = () => {
    setSwipeEnabled(false);
  };

  const handleScrollEnd = () => {
    setSwipeEnabled(true);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView
      onScrollBeginDrag={handleScrollBegin}
      onScrollEndDrag={handleScrollEnd}
    >
      {data.map(item => (
        <SwipeRow key={item.id} item={item} swipeEnabled={swipeEnabled} />
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```